# API Amazon Product Advertising

Tags: asp.net, webforms, amazon-aws

Estou usando a API de terceiros (Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) para buscar livros e demais itens no Catalogo da Amazon, quando a aplicação estava em teste não apresentou qualquer erro, foi só colocar no ar uns 7 dias depois, começou a retornar erro "RequestThrottled" vc precisa ficar dando uns 3 F5 na pagina para aparecer os produtos, já pesquisei nos fóruns da Amazon e dizem este erro é de muitos acessos simultâneos... ( 15 dias no ar ???)

Alguém sabe como resolver ou contornar isto?

Answer (score 0):

RequestThrottled é uma forma da Amazon de evitar que você fique fazendo muitas requisições a sua API em um curto intervalo de tempo (De acordo com eles, a cada 1 segundo é possível apenas 1 requisição). É uma prática usada para evitar ataques DDOS por exemplo, quando requisitado muitas vezes a API vai começar negar acesso a requisições que utilizem a mesma rede.

De acordo com a própria Amazon:

> If your application is trying to submit requests that exceed the
>   maximum request for your account, you may receive error messages from
>   Product Advertising API. The request limit for each account is
>   calculated based on revenue performance. Each account used to access
>   the Product Advertising API is allowed an initial usage limit of 1
>   request per second*. Each account will receive an additional 1 request
>   per second (up to a maximum of 10) for every $4,600 of shipped item
>   revenue driven in a trailing 30-day period (about $0.11 per minute).

Aparentemente a única forma de contornar esse problema é aumentando as vendas. Não sei dizer se a Amazon aceita outra forma de aumentar a quantidade de request.

[Referência](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html)

Comment: Então Gabriel, eu já tinha visto esta explicação em um fórum também, mas porque em teste não acontecia isto ( 2 meses ) podia dar 3, 4 refresh na tela sempre aparecia o produto, isto começou depois de 7 dias no ar, agora é incongruente vc ter um site aonde vc tem q pausar suas açoes ( colocar avisos clique 3 x para aparecer o produto.. )  eu acho que perdi meu tempo... valeu !!! abraços.

Comment: Concordo com você. Você utilizava a mesma API para sua homologação? Não era uma de teste?

Comment: Não a mesma, mesmo com um subdomínio e na maquina local

Comment: Não tem esta àrea de homologação ( fiz o cadastro de associado e foi gerado as chaves ) somente isto...